# log4Net - Loggers between classes - Releasing a File

Tags: log4net

I am new to log4net. Here is my app.config. What is happening is at a point after going through a switch statement, my logger "X" stops writing to my log file. I tried x.Logger.Repository.Shutdown();, and all that does is stop my "Y" from even logging. My suspicion is that the file is in use, and can't be written to (the next logging statement does begin in a different class. Again, I'm new. Basically, it writes about 10 lines, goes to another class with a logger of the same name, works in that class for a few more lines, and then when it goes back to the original class, it stops logging. I'm a little lost. P.S. I have the correct section name, and I am calling my log as such: 
    private static readonly ILog eventLog = LogManager.GetLogger("EventLog");

```
<appender type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" name="event">
<file value="C:X.log" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
<conversionpattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
</layout>
</appender>

<appender type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" name="cLog">
<file value="Y.log" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
<conversionpattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
</layout>
</appender>

<logger name="EventLog">
<level value="INFO" />
<maximumfilesize value="256KB" />
<param value="INFO" name="Threshold" />
<appender-ref ref="event" />
</logger>

<logger name="crLog">
<level value="INFO" />
<maximumfilesize value="256KB" />
<param value="INFO" name="Threshold" />
<appender-ref ref="cLog" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, when you call x.Logger.Repository.Shutdown(); it kills any logs that you might want to write to at that point in time. 
I will either move x.Logger.Repository.Shutdown(), or find a different method for releasing my files so the last portion of my app can use (email) the file.